# Symfony2 EntityManager Updating without persist

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entitymanager

As you can see below, I do not "persist" at all. But the changes I make are registering. I would appreciate your help.

`$entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
 $entity = $entityManager->getRepository(City::class)->find(1);
 $entity->setName("debug name");
 $entityManager->flush();`

Comment: I don't see any problem there as what you're doing is an UPDATE process. You don't have to call `persist` to trigger update cos you're already calling `flush`. [Described here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#updating-an-object)

Comment: $em->refresh($entity) will basically undo any changes made to $entity since it was last retrieved.

Answer (score 13):

You have to call method `persist()` when initializing a new object, like `new City()`. When you fetch object from database with `find()` it already has some metadata.

[From doctrine website](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.9/reference/working-with-objects.html#working-with-objects):

> Doctrine uses the Identity Map pattern to track objects. Whenever you
> fetch an object from the database, Doctrine will keep a reference to
> this object inside its UnitOfWork. The array holding all the entity
> references is two-levels deep and has the keys “root entity name” and
> “id”.

Here is example from doctrine:

> When you call EntityManager#flush Doctrine will ask the identity map
> for all objects that are currently managed. This means you don’t have
> to call EntityManager#persist over and over again to pass known
> objects to the EntityManager. This is a NO-OP for known entities, but
> leads to much code written that is confusing to other developers.
>
> The following code WILL update your database with the changes made to
> the Person object, even if you did not call EntityManager#persist:

```
<?php
$user = $entityManager->find("Person", 1);
$user->setName("Guilherme");
$entityManager->flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

just detach your found entity after you load it from repository

```
$entity = $entityManager->getRepository(City::class)->find(1);    
$entityManager->detach($entity);
```